# sublime text 3 file tabs changed with update (too wide/too smart?)

Tags: sublimetext3

A new update to sublime text 3 seems to have changed the way the file tabs work. I'm not even sure what is the proper element for this name but something happened with this:

[image]

Before this most recent update, i think the tabs would just shrink as the number increased, and not being able to read the name was a signal that i need to close stuff. Now it feels a lot smarter, it makes sure that i can read the entire name, but then a whole bunch of them can be hidden and stacked at the very beginning or end. I dont like this, how can i change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `"enable_tab_scrolling": false,` in your user preferences to get the old ST2 behavior back.